# How do you change a data type of a table field in ms access without having to create a new form to update the table?

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a customerID as a primary key (Autonumber) and when I put customerID on another table I left it as short text instead of obviously number data type and I only realised after I created my forms and queries. Is there a way of changing data type and still being able to update my table using the forms I created with having to delete relationship, fix and redo all my forms?

When I change the data type this message appears "Some data will be lost. the setting for the fieldsize property of one or more fields has been changed to a shorter size. if data is lost, validation rules may be violated as a result"

Comment: The warning says "may be lost". If you have no data in the field, then nothing to lose, if the data is all numeric then nothing should be lost. Unfortunately, deleting and resetting relationship cannot be avoided. Form and Control properties will probably have to be edited but should not have to rebuild forms from scratch. What relationship was set?

Comment: The ID data is all populated but with short text in foreign fields it just won't update the table from form properly. I have a lot of forms and a menu leading to them so it seems too much effort.

Comment: Not too much effort if the end result is an improvement. It may be tedious and time-consuming but do it right and only do it the one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

always create a new column and copy into it the data you're going to convert before trying the conversion, jic. new column name: `customerID_bak`. copy all customerID data into it and try the conversion. if something goes wrong, you still have the original data. i think you actually might not have an issue with your forms after the conversion.